# Prove that for a dense set $A$ and an open set $U$, $U\subset \overline{A\cap U}$

Tags: general-topology

In a topological space $X$ a subset $A$ is called dense if $\overline{A}=X$. Show that for a dense set $A$ and an open set $U$

$U\subset \overline{A\cap U}$

My solution

$U$ is open $\Rightarrow$ $U \subset \overline{U}$ 
and also $U \subset X$

$\Rightarrow$ $U \subset \overline{U} \cap X $

Since $A$ is dense in $X$ $(\overline{A}=X)$

$\Rightarrow$ $U \subset \overline{U} \cap \overline{A} $

$\Rightarrow$ $U \subset \overline{U \cap A }$

Does this proof looks good or I missed something.

Comment: The last proposition isn't what you're trying to prove. Why would you think this is a proof? If it's a typo, note that closure doesn't distribute over intersection.

Comment: @Matt: Sorry that was a typo. Closure wont distribute. I need to think more about that.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Thanks for your input. Closure indeed would not distribute.

Comment: @MattSamuel: I believe that I can still salvage my proof since $\overline{U} \cap \overline{A} \subset \overline{U \cap A }$. This is true because if $x\in (\overline{U} \cap \overline{A})$ then every open ball containing $x$ would have to intersect (in a non empty fashion) with both $U$ and $A$ while if $x\in \overline{U \cap A }$ then very open ball containing $x$ would have to intersect (in a non empty fashion) with either $U$ and $A$. Thus $\overline{U} \cap \overline{A} \subset \overline{U \cap A }$. I would appreciate if you can comment.

Comment: You have mixed up the direction; only the opposite containment is true. For example, let $C=\{-1/n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $D=\{1/n|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then $\overline{C\cap D}=\emptyset$ but $\overline{C}\cap\overline{D}=\{0\}$.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Thank you. I did mix up the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in U$

Let $V$ be an open set containing $x$ then $x\in U\cap V$ since $A$ is dense any non empty open set intersects $A$

so $A\cap(U\cap V)\neq $ empty thus $x\in \overline {(A\cap U)}$

Comment: In this case why would we even introduce $V$. Can we just say since A is dense $A\cap(U)\neq$ empty thus $x\in \overline {(A\cap U)}$

Comment: $x\in \overline A\implies $ every open set containing $x$ intersects $A$